# Is this code potentially dangerous?

Tags: c#, crash, for-loop, system

I'm just a fool who finds such kiddy script tools fascinating :)

```
        for(i = 0; i < 100000000000000000000000; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process StartTheKill;
            StartTheKill = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            StartTheKill.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            string TheCommand;
            TheCommand = "/C tree C:/";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", TheCommand);
            StartTheKill.Close();
        }
```

My teacher tough me this because it's a great tool for checking fault hard drives. I just wonder if this loop would be enough to crash the PC or cause permanent damage to the hardware...

Comment: You don't need help with that. It won't compile let alone crash your system. Also, learn to write a batch file instead :)

Comment: I'm using this from GUI, this is just a part of code from the button  click event, the main part which I have interest in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt this would even crash the machine.

Each process will take some memory, and you'll soon run out of memory at which point the OS will refuse to start any more tasks.  You'll probably see a nice dialog about running low on virtual memory.

Damage the hardware?  you must be joking.

Comment: Since he raised the issue of damaging the hardware, I've only heard of two programs that actually did so.  One set the Vertical and Horizontal refresh rates of an old CRT to 0, so that the scanning beam was focused in the middle of the screen until it burned out.   Another malicious piece of software repeatedly sent the Hard Disk a "reset" command, causing the head to repeatedly slam into a stopper at its extreme outer position until it was damaged.  Neither is possible on modern hardware anymore.

Comment: Interesting. Such simple yet so surprising.